# Struts2 - Question about AJAX implementation

Tags: ajax, struts2

I new on Struts2, and i need to do some AJAX call to the server.

I tried to search some tutorial, but expect roseindia ones, i don't find nothing.
Also, i don't understand if Struts2 implements natively Ajax or if i must use it with some library (like Dojo or Jquery?).

Also, can you give to me some good tutorial?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Struts2 is an MVC framework for building server-side web applications and Ajax is a concept that exists within the client-side of things. From the server's perspective, it just needs to respond to an HTTP request (which happens to come from JavaScript for Ajax).

Therefore, Struts2 does not "implement Ajax." You'll need to use JavaScript (or a JavaScript framework like jQuery, Dojo, etc.) as you mentioned.

You can use these in Struts2 just as you would in any web project, by including the necessary JavaScript and CSS files, or you can use a Struts2 plugin (there are plugins for both previously mentioned libraries).

I'm pretty sure that the jQuery and Dojo plugins contain tag libraries for doing Ajax.

Comment: Ah. that's strange anyway! Struts2 is a must as frameworks. Already, the JSF implements his natively Ajax standard. It's strange that Struts doesnt use it, isnt it?

Comment: No, I don't find it strange at all. Struts2 doesn't need to make assumptions about what Ajax library I want to use in my applications. It's incredibly easy to choose a plug-in to handle that or to just use one of those libraries just as you would if you were writing PHP or Ruby. :)

Comment: Ok. I recently used JSF, and i see that is really nice thing had Ajax functions implemented on it. Also because you work in a MVC place, which is different than PHP/Ruby! But ok, maybe Im wrong :) I'll try some functions on Struts2 with Jquery and i'll let you know...

Answer (score 1):

we use the [struts 2 json plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jsonplugin/) for returning json from struts actions.

on the client side, you'll likely want to use a javascript framework like jQuery to issue your ajax calls and then handle the json response.